# Find $\tan(\arctan(\frac{1}{3})+\arctan(\frac{1}{9}))$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

Why is this incorrect? Everything is according to the formula: $$\tan(\arctan(\frac{1}{3})+\arctan(\frac{1}{9}))=\frac{\tan(\arctan(\frac{1}{3}))+\tan(\arctan(\frac{1}{9}))}{1-\tan(\arctan(\frac{1}{3}))\tan(\frac{1}{9})}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Evaluating the RHS is
$$
\frac{1/3 + 1/9}{1 - 1/27} = \frac{27}{26} \frac{4}{9} = \frac{6}{13} \ne 1/2
$$

Comment: He means the LHS.

Comment: Left hand side, right hand side.

Comment: You seem to have made a mistake when reducing the complex fraction. $\dfrac{\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{9}}{1-\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{9}}\cdot\dfrac{27}{27}=$?

Comment: You somehow reduced the complex fraction to $\frac{1}{2}$ when it clearly reduces to $\dfrac{9+3}{27-1}=\dfrac{12}{26}=\dfrac{6}{13}$ as indicated in the answer given by @gt6989b .

Comment: A fraction which contains a fraction in the numerator or denominator is known as a **complex fraction** . Fractions contained in the numerator or denominator are known as the **minor fractions** of the complex fraction. The surest way to **reduce** a complex fraction to an **ordinary fraction** is to multiply both the numerator and the denominator by the least common denominator of the minor fractions. The LCD in this particular case was $27$.